# A picture is worth a thousand words

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

So what is the meaning of these pictures?

[image: pictures]

Comment: [tag:rebus] tag?

Comment: No, no rebus tag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These pictures say:

> **Pictionary avant la lettre**

How so?

> Each of the pictures represents a letter of the Phoenician or [Proto-Sinaitic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Sinaitic_script). These early alphabets are derived from hieroglyphs and represent letters by everyday things. (Perhaps you have seen images that show how the shape the Greek letter alpha and our [Latin latter A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A) derive from the horned head of an ox turnd on its side.)
>
>  In particular, the letters are:
>
> ```
>     P   pit     corner
>     I   yad     hand
>     C   gaml    throwing stick
>     T   taw     mark
>     I   yad     hand
>     O   ayn     eye
>     N   nahas   snake
>     A   alp     ox
>     R   ras     head
>     Y   waw     fowl
>
>     A   alp     ox
>     V   waw     fowl
>     A   alp     ox
>     N   nahas   snake
>     T   taw     mark
>
>     L   lamd    goad
>     A   alp     ox
>
>     L   lamd    goad
>     E   haw     praise
>     T   taw     mark
>     T   taw     mark
>     R   ras     head
>     E   haw     praise
> ```

What does it mean?

> In a way, it could just mean what the title says: Pictures trump letters. But [avant la lettre](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/avant_la_lettre) can also refer to a term applied to something before the term was coined. The early alphabets were [Pictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pictionary) *avant la lettre*.

Comment: That's it, well done!